# Show Time and data using Data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I wanted to know whats is the best data type for time value only also is there a data annotation for the same ?

Also I wanted to know is there a way to format datatype datetime using Data annotation to display date and time(eg: `dd-mm-yy HH:MM AM/PM`)

Comment: Use `TimeSpan` for times. Use `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "...")]` for formatting dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object is of type DateTime then you can simply use `.ToString()` method for print it in required format, by passing the format string as argument to the .ToString(). Consider the following example:

```
 DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now; // let it be 27-06-2016 13:06
 string format = "dd-MM-yy HH:MM tt";
 string formatedDateTime = currentDate.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Note :** You can find more format options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx),and a working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DL7ek4)

Answer (score 3):

```
        [DisplayName("Proposed commisioning Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime CommisioningDate { set; get; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

go to this link and use your required date time fromat