# MVC EditorFor Date not showing Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display a date in German date format (dd.MM.yyyy) from the model in an MVC app and provide the user a datepicker. I've gone throug a lot of the questions that have already been answered on this topic, but still can't get it to work. I tried it in  Firefox and Edge, with the same results for each step.

**Step 1:**

Model:

```
private DateTime? inbetriebnahmedatum;

public DateTime? Inbetriebnahmedatum
{               
    get { return inbetriebnahmedatum; }
    set { inbetriebnahmedatum = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Inbetriebnahmedatum")); }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Inbetriebnahmedatum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Datum eingeben" } })
```

Result: No Datepicker, Time is displayed, Validation error
[image]

**Step 2: Added DataType**

Model:

```
private DateTime? inbetriebnahmedatum;

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? Inbetriebnahmedatum
{
    get { return inbetriebnahmedatum; }
    set { inbetriebnahmedatum = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Inbetriebnahmedatum")); }
}
```

View: unchanged

Result: Value not loaded.
[image]

**Step 3: DisplayFormat added, Datatype removed**

Model:

```
private DateTime? inbetriebnahmedatum;

[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
public DateTime? Inbetriebnahmedatum
{
    get { return inbetriebnahmedatum; }
    set { inbetriebnahmedatum = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Inbetriebnahmedatum")); }
}
```

View: unchanged

Result: Date displayed, but no datepicker and Validation Error
[image]

**Step 4: Addedd ui Culture to Web.config**

Web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="de-DE" culture="de-DE" />
```

Result: Same
[image]

**Step 5: Added Datatype again**

Model:

```
private DateTime? inbetriebnahmedatum;

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
public DateTime? Inbetriebnahmedatum
{
    get { return inbetriebnahmedatum; }
    set { inbetriebnahmedatum = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Inbetriebnahmedatum")); }
}
```

Result: Value not loaded, datepicker shows
[image]

Comment: The `DataFormatString` must be `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format) when generating the browsers HTML-5 datepicker, and then it will be displayed in the users culture which is the whole point of using it.

Comment: Use a jQuery datepicker (e.g. jQueryUI) but then you will also need to reconfigure the `$.validator` for client side validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: You are right, now it works - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but u can try this 
try enter as like >> :   **01/01/2018**

or

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}")]
```

**or**

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

[Show Time and data using Data annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048132/show-time-and-data-using-data-annotation)