# MVC/JQuery validation does not accept comma as decimal separator

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Update 07.01.2018**

Even though it was suggested, that this is rather a jQuery problem than an MS ASP MVC problem, I think it is an MVC Problem. I've created the whole app in asp.net core 2.0 MVC and the error persist. What links it to MVC for me, is the fact that I can solve the date validation problem by adding the line `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]` to the model. Hence, MVC has an influence on the validation. So I would assume there is some way in MVC to fix this (See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041115/mvc-editorfor-date-not-showing-value)). Please post answers for asp.net core 2.0.

**Original Post**

In an MVC5 page I render a `Double` Property in a Textbox. When the page is loaded, the value is shown with a "," as decimal separator, which is correct, as the page runs on an German System. If I want to save the form, I get an validation error. How can this be solved? I know that there are some questions on the topic, but as far as i can see, most of them are outdated... I'm still struggling, that there is no setting or anything built-in that allows users from different countries to work with MVC apps.

Model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Double Gewicht
{
    get { return gewicht; }
    set { gewicht = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Gewicht")); }
}
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gewicht, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gewicht, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-1" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gewicht, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="de-DE" culture="de-DE" />
```

Box after its loaded --> Value loaded with a comma as decimal separator
[image]

Box after submit button is clicked --> Validation error for the same value

[image]

Box after comma is changed to point --> No validation error
[image]

**Update 05.01.2018**

I've tried the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app) which unfortunately doesn't work for me. However, I also discovered, that the values not only get not acceptet, but are also changed to numbers where group separator and decimal separator are mixed up (see picture). What happens is, that the value of 22 gets changed to 22.5 and stored in the database. The result beeing, that a value of 2,250.00 is stored to the database.

[image]

**Update 07.01.2018**

What is also interesting, is the fact that the date fields accept the german format perfectly fine.

Property

```
private DateTime? inbetriebnahmedatum;

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? Inbetriebnahmedatum
{
    get { return inbetriebnahmedatum; }
    set { inbetriebnahmedatum = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Inbetriebnahmedatum")); }
}
```

The value shown below is accepted and processed without any errors. 
[image]

**Update 07.01.2018 - 2**

If I change the line in edit.cshtml from

```
<input asp-for="Gewicht" class="form-control" />
```

to

```
<input name="Gewicht" id="Gewicht" type="number" class="form-control" value="@Model.Gewicht"/>
```

The form can be submitted with the value "23,7" without validation errors. In the controller, the bound model property shows a value of "237", where as the `IFormCollection` shows a value of "23.7". This would suggest a problem with the model binder.

Comment: I don't think this is similar, since I use `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` and I'm fine with the format. Also I hope that there is a more "built in" way to solve this, since I can't imagine that MVC 5 doesn't allow to save decimal values in other formats than us-US.

Comment: @Mister832 that has nothing to do with MVC5. The error you saw is produced by jquery validate javascript library. You can define a custom validator to handle comma

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title. I just thougt, that it has something to do with the data annotation in the base class.

Comment: Perhaps use your own model binder if you haven't set your culture properly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793459/how-to-set-decimal-separators-in-asp-net-mvc-controllers

Comment: I don't think the culture is a problem, since the datepicker works fine, i.e. display in german date format is stored perfectly well.

Comment: The is a client side issue, not a mvc issue. By default, the `jquery.validate.js` script validates numbers using a `.` (dot) as the decimal separator. You need to reconfigure the validator to use a `,` (comma) as a the decimal separator

Comment: I agree that this is a client side issue. However, I can fix the similar issue for date field with the annotaion `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]` (which btw I learned with the help of @StephenMuecke) in MVC. I would expect the same to be possible for decimal fields, as there are more ways to influence the clientside validation with MVC annotation, like max length, pattern aso.

Comment: @Mister832, The datepicker works because the format is ISO format. The answer by Dans is one way to solve the issue (or you can use a plugin such as [jquery.globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize)). There is no way to do 'fix it' using server side code

Comment: You might be interested in [this plugin](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-numericinput) which displays and validates input for numeric types based on the server culture

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Even though it was suggested, that this is rather a jQuery problem than an MVC problem, I think it is an MVC Problem.

No that is no correct. You seeing a client side validation error because, by default, `jquery.validate.js` (an independent 3rd party plugin not associated with MicroSoft, that MVC uses for client side validation) validates numbers based on the decimal separator being a `.` (dot), not a `,` (comma).

MVC is server side code and does not run in the browser. To perform client side validation, MVC's `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls render a set of `data-val-*` attributes in the html used to describe the validation to be performed, which are in turn parsed by the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugin when the DOM is loaded, and uses those to add rules to the `$.validator`.

In the case of your `double` property it will add a `data-val-number` attribute (in addition to `data-val-required` attribute), which will add the `number` rule which is defined as

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number
number: function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
},
```

where the decimal separator is a dot, and the thousands separator is a comma (presumably because the plugin was developed in the US, so uses a US format).

You need to overwrite the default behavior which you can do by using plugins such as [jquery.globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize), or including the following script (note the regex just swaps the dot and comma)

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)?(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```

Note the above script needs to be after the `jquery.validate.js` script but not wrapped in `$(document).ready()`

> What links it to MVC for me, is the fact that I can solve the date validation problem by adding the line `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]` to the model.

Its actually your `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute in conjunction with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute that is influencing the html that is generated. The `[DataType]` attribute generates `<input type="date" ... />` which in turn renders the browsers HTML-5 datepicker if the browser supports it. In accordance with the specifications the format must be `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format) hence the need for the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute as well.

The HTML-5 datepicker renders the date in the browsers culture. The image you have shown where the input is `26.1.2018` is because your browser culture is `de-DE`, but if I navigated to your site, I would see `26/1/2018` in the input because my culture is `en-AU` (Australian), and if a United States user navigated to your site, they would see `1/26/2018`.

The reason client side validation works for the date property is that the `jquery.validate.js` plugin includes date rules for both US format (`MM/dd/yyyy`) and ISO format (`yyyy-MM-dd`).

And if you were to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Inbetriebnahmedatum)` (which ignores your `[DataType]` and `[DisplayFormat]` attributes), and entered `26.1.2018` in the input, you would also see a client side validation error.

Comment: This works great for the number method. However if you use Range attributes in your model, you also need to change the range method in Javascript. Otherwise a number is gonna be evaluated as bigger, because of all the zeroes after a comma.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is jquery validator
i'v used thus for resolve the comma/point error

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```

just try play with it

Comment: Thanks, but as stated, the intention is to use the whole thing with out of the box functionalities. As cool as this "oneliner" looks, whats point of an MVC application, when I still have to fiddle around with things like that? Especially, when you watch the MVA videos, where they praise how easy web interface design becomes with an "model-only" approach...

Answer (score 3):

A more robust solution might be to wrap the validator methods in your own function which converts your comma separated number to one that is decimal separated.

One trick is to use .call to call the original validator function as if "this" was the original this that the developers thought (e.g. they use a function "this.optional" for their step validation).

```
var originalNumber = $.validator.methods.number;
var wrappedNumber = function (value, element) {
    var fixedValue = parseFloat(value.toString().replace(",", "."));
    return originalNumber.call($.validator.prototype, fixedValue, element);     // Call function as if "this" is the original caller
};
$.validator.methods.number = wrappedNumber;
```

You could make this work for any validator, e.g. the step validation:

```
var originalStep = $.validator.methods.step;
var wrappedStep = function (value, element, param) {
    var fixedValue = parseFloat(value.toString().replace(",", "."));
    return originalStep.call($.validator.prototype, fixedValue, element, param);
};
$.validator.methods.step = wrappedStep;
```

Comment: Like this solution but it is important to point out that `parseFloat` is not enough for the number transformation as for example `parseFloat("50-ba")` returns `5`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As with almost anything in programming, the answer is "it depends". We pursued a different approach mimicking <input type="number"> for <input type="text" class="number-input"> but for danish locale by limiting the input to 0-9 and one "," character with js.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the number method to allow for comma decimal separator and you use the Range attribute in your model class. You need to also overwrite the range method:

```
const originalRange = $.validator.methods.range;
var wrappedRange = function (value, element, param) {
    var fixedValue2 = parseFloat(value.toString().replace(",", "."));
    return originalRange.call($.validator.prototype, fixedValue2, element, param);
};
$.validator.methods.range = wrappedRange;
```