# ASP.NET MVC Editorfor for Decimal

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My column name  is  `Total decimal(18, 2)` on SQL SERVER,

in my model `public Nullable<decimal> Total { get; set; }`

and my .cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fatura_Tutar, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Total </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Total , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

So,When I clicked the edit button "Total " comes like for example "1020,00"
and click save it gives validation eror, it must be integer. but if I delete ",00" and like "1020" it will accept. How can I modify my editorfor

Comment: What is Total's type? Is it int? If so you would need to set as decimal. A period would also need to be used to store the value.

Comment: No, Total is decimal not int and here is the problem

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822480/error-with-decimal-in-mvc3-the-value-is-not-valid-for-field

Comment: maybe but i think its a simple problem,i guess it has easier way to fix

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066208/mvc-jquery-validation-does-not-accept-comma-as-decimal-separator

Comment: Your question has 1020,00. Is it not supposed to be 1020.00?

Comment: No it is really "1020,00" not "."